# For $p>2$ prime, $\sqrt p$ is not a linear combination (with rational coefficients) of 1 and $\sqrt 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'd like to show that for $p>2$ prime, $\sqrt p$ is not a linear combination (using rational coefficients) of 1 and $\sqrt 2$.

The only related proof that comes to mind is the proof that $\sqrt 2$ is not rational, which is by contradiction. So I will attempt by contradiction, first showing that $\sqrt p$ is not a rational multiple of $\sqrt 2$:

For $p>2$ prime given, suppose $\sqrt p=a\sqrt 2$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Q}$. Equivalently, $p/2=a^2 \Leftrightarrow p=2a^2.$ It looks almost like $p$ is divisible by 2, which would be a contradiction with $p>2$ prime. But $a^2$ need not be an integer, so we're not quite there.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hint: suppose $\sqrt{p}=a\cdot 1+b\sqrt{2}$ and square both sides.

Comment: Write $\sqrt p=a+b\sqrt 2$ and square both sides.

Comment: Note:  to complete your argument, if $a=\frac mn$ in least terms then show first that $n$ is even and then deduce that $m$ is also even, contradicting the "least terms".

Comment: Trying the first hint gives me $p=a^2+\sqrt 2ab+2b=a(\sqrt p )+ 2b \Leftrightarrow p-a\sqrt p -2b=0$, so $p=\frac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2+8b}}{2}$. Still failing to see the contradiction.. $p$ is a rational plus or minus a square root of a rational.